# Git pipeline job fails with CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE: Permission denied

Tags: gitlab

my goal is to create a GitLab CI/CD pipeline in repo_A that clones a separate repo_B. Here is the pipeline that I have in repo A:

```
stages:
  - clone-repo

clone-repo-job:
  stage: clone-repo
  script:
    - git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@hostname/group/repo_B
```

In the Token Access section of the CI/CD settings for repo_B, I added repo_A so that it allows CI job tokens from repo_A.

When I run the pipeline, I get the following output:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.7.0 (102c81ba)
  on hostname ixxkmE1bM, system ID: xxxxxxxxxxx
Resolving secrets
Preparing the "shell" executor
Using Shell (bash) executor...
Preparing environment
Running on hostname...
Getting source from Git repository
bash: line 45: /home/gitlab-runner/builds/ixxkmE1bM/0/group_name/repo_A.tmp/CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE: Permission denied
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I wish the error was a little more descriptive. Does this mean that the gitlab-runner user account doesn't have permissions to clone repo_B? I thought the whole point of the CI_JOB_TOKEN and Token Access settings were to allow that to happen?

I found some folks with similar issues, but the solutions that worked for them are not working for me. What is my permissions issue exactly?